# Jquery Script only loading after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script which is a slide-up hover effect, it only loads though when you refresh the page for some reason. This is really annoying...

I think it could be to do with me calling it in the html as a script:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.bb-slide-cap').mosaic({
        animation: 'slide', //fade or slide
        speed: 600,
        preload: 1
    });

});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JJDn7/3/

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me even after refreshing the page (Chrome).

Comment: I wonder if the $ in `jQuery(function ($) {` is giving you fits. Try it without `jQuery(function () {`. And in the JSFiddle I changed it to run in <head> rather than onLoad.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles That's the correct way to write it. You use this syntax if you have another library loaded that uses `$`. This allows you to use the `$` shorthand as a local variable inside the body of the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/JJDn7/8/embedded/result/ Is this you neeed

Comment: if you are using mosaic plugin , go through this https://github.com/buildinternet/mosaic/blob/master/examples.html

Comment: Hi @dev, yeah that fiddle you posted seems to work, is it because you put the function in the head?

Comment: I doesnt matter but in case of two scripts sharing $ i thought i wrap in head. If its working for you real challenge then its good give it a try in your real challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesnt matter but in case of two scripts sharing $ i thought i wrap in head. If its working for you real challenge then its good give it a try in your real challenge.

The link for other readers if it solves your issue.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.bb-slide-cap').mosaic({
        animation: 'slide', //fade or slide
        speed: 600,
        preload: 1
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/JJDn7/8/embedded/result)